# Are sample memory access traces/dumps available, and where?

Tags: cpu-cache, memory-hardware, simulation, memory-access

I am looking for a realistic physical memory access trace/dump of significant, but not insane, length (on the order of 1M accesses) for the purpose of cache simulation. Preferably for a 16-bit or 32-bit RAM. Preferably in Tarmac format. The actual architecture is irrelevant. Are such files publicly available, and if so, where can I find them? (Googling did not help.)

Comment: Your best bet might be to generate such a memory trace yourself, by instrumenting a single program or an interpreter for some architecture (e.g., Bochs).  I'm not sure that requests for data sets are on topic here.

Comment: @D.W. I could not find requests for data sets on the list of off topic questions. Also, when I was a grad student (30 years ago), we had access to sample memory traces and used them precisely to simulate caches. So, unless those traces evaporated in the last 30 years, I hope that someone still knows where to find them.

Comment: OK!  You might be right!  My initial reaction might have been off-base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incidentally, I found an answer to my question: `valgrind`, when instrumented with `lackey` tool, can capture reliable, though not perfect, traces. For example, here's how one saves the trace for `ls -l`:

```
$ valgrind --log-fd=1 --tool=lackey -v --trace-mem=yes ls -l > trace.log
```

Hope it helps not just me but others as well.

Comment: You could also use SimpleScalar if you don't mind an artificial CPU. This is useful is you need to control for details like the specifics of operating systems.